# Unable to intent after inserting data into mysql

Tags: android, mysql, android-intent

I am inserting my data in `MySql`, and the data is inserting successfully. But i am not able to `Intent` to different `Activity` after the successful operation.
Here is my code :

```
public void registerfinish(View view) {
    ...
    new finalRegister().execute();
}

class finalRegister extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        ...
    }

    /**
     * getting All products from url
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        ...
        // getting JSON Object
        // Note that create product url accepts POST method
        JSONObject json = null ;

        try {
            json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url,
                    "GET", params);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



        // check for success tag

        try {
            // check log cat fro response
            Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());
            success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (success == 1) {
                // successfully created product
                Intent i = new Intent(Register2ndStep.this, FinalScreen.class);
                startActivity(i);

                // closing this screen
                //finish();
            } else {
                ...
            }
        return null;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
        pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

}
```

Logcat:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at wolverine.example.com.btp_scientist.Register2ndStep$finalRegister.doInBackground(Register2ndStep.java:220)
        at wolverine.example.com.btp_scientist.Register2ndStep$finalRegister.doInBackground(Register2ndStep.java:173)

Register2ndStep.java:220:  Log.d("Create Response", json.toString())
Register2ndStep.java:173:   class finalRegister extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13296114/4070044  - take  a look

Comment: @shine_joseph it didn't work for me..

Answer (score 0):

Just move your intent code to onPostExecute method:

```
 protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
         Intent i = new Intent(Register2ndStep.this, FinalScreen.class);
         startActivity(i);
         pDialog.dismiss();
   }
```

Comment: Same result...The Application is crashing

Comment: Yes i did. But, i think my problem is in json.toString() which probably giving error.

Comment: when you calling `jsonParser.makeHttpRequest` your sending `param` as argument. Check `jsonParser` or `params` or '`json` if any of them is null, do a debug or put Log to print in console.